# Error Running Java Application OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing

I am currently working on a Java game for OSX (and possibly Windows in the future) - I decided to export a Pre-Alpha / Alpha test of the game - to see if the engine was working properly outside of Eclipse. When I tried to run the application it quit almost instantly, throwing the following errors (in Console):

`14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus: [JavaAppLauncher Error] CallStaticVoidMethod() threw an exception
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus: Exception in thread "main" 
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ten/plus/Game : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
14-07-29 8:57:02.190 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.loadMainMethod(LaunchRunner.java:56)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:112)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain(LaunchRunner.java:51)
14-07-29 8:57:02.191 AM [0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus:  at apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.launch(JavaApplicationLauncher.java:52)
14-07-29 8:57:02.220 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: ([0x0-0x1c21c2].10Plus[3659]) Exited with code: 1`

I know the code will throw a few IOExceptions - mainly due to image loading but it's all surrounded by try/catch and doesn't break the application when I remove the image files and run it in Eclipse.

Some notes about the application:
It runs in fullscreen at the native resolution of the device - in my case 1680 x 1050 - but it doesn't act like a normal fullscreen application. For example: In most fullscreen applications if you move your mouse to the top of the screen and wit a second or two the apple menu bar comes down (with the time, etc...) but not with this. I'm not sure if this has to be coded specifically but it's not a feature I really need.
I use the thread but it is not called 'main' - which makes me wonder about: `Exception in Thread "main"`
The application should run in 1.6+ as that's the version I chose when exporting from Eclipse.
Finally I use both AWT and SWING. AWT for graphics, KeyListener etc... and SWING for window handling.

Some notes about my computer software / hardware:
I am running OSX 10.7.5 on a MacBook Pro 15 inch - early 2011 - as I said earlier my resolution is 1680x1050.
According to Java Preferences I am running Java 8 Update 11, but according to Terminal I am running Java 6 Update 65 - both SE. (When I open Minecraft I get this towards the end of the launcher's boot `[09:48:29 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.6.0_65'`)

The last working export I have is my final export from Eclipse Kepler - I believe it's 1.4.3. That version had no IO whatsoever and ran in a 1200x875 window.

This is my first export from Luna - 1.4.4 if I'm correct.

I will try exporting the application in different versions of Java with both Kepler and Luna - in case the Luna exporter or Java version is the problem.

Thanks in advance!

PLEASE NOTE: I am beginner/intermediate in Java so please excuse me if I made some obvious mistake somewhere.

Comment: Google this error as it's common. You're trying to run the program on a JVM that is a lower version than the one that it was compiled with. Solution: Update your computer's Java.

Comment: ... or compile with current computer's Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you have compiled your code on Java version X, you are trying to run program on Java version less than X. The version to run the program should be >= X. So always try to compile program on the lowest version of Java which is expected to be used by users.